# How can I respond the request from an authorization middleware in a Next.js api route?

Tags: node.js, authentication, next.js, middleware

Let's say I have the following Next.js api route.

`/api/protected-api`

This api will get a `authorization: "Bearer: TOKEN"` header for authorization purposes.

```
import { NextApiHandler } from "next";

const apiHandler: NextApiHandler = async (req, res) => {

  await runAuthMiddleware(req,res);

  // THE REST OF THE API LOGIC SHOULD ONLY RUN IF AUTHORIZATION SUCCEEDS
  // IN THEORY, runAuthMiddleware WOULD RESPOND WITH 403 IF AUTHORIZATION FAILS

  return res.json(data);

};
```

What I mean by the code above is:

- If authorization fails, I would like to respond a `403` from the `runAuthMiddleware` function, and don't even bother running the rest of the code in the `apiHandler`.

Is this even possible? Is this an anti-pattern?

Should I got with something like this instead?

```
const apiHandler: NextApiHandler = async (req, res) => {

  const authSuccess = await runAuthMiddleware(req,res);

  if (authSuccess)
    return res.json(data);
  else
    return res.status(403).send("Forbidden");

};
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems that there's no easy way of doing it. This package offers a possible solution: [next-api-middleware](https://github.com/htunnicliff/next-api-middleware)

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do it if that is the only thing that you need, just make your own higher order function which checks auth:

```
const withAuth = (f) => async (req, res) => {
  const isLogged = await checkIfUserIsLogged(req)

  if (isLogged) {
    return f(req, res)
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send("Forbidden");
  }
}

const apiHandler = withAuth(async (req, res) => {
  // This code now only runs of the user is logged
  return res.json(data);
});
```

For more complex scenarios I would recommend to use https://github.com/hoangvvo/next-connect or something like that. But if you only need one middleware then it is completely fine to write your own.